# How to work with Google Suggest queries using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-api, autosuggest

I am trying to work with the Google API for suggest queries. But I am getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=sheikh+hasina',
  type:"GET",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp:function (data) {
    console.log('yes');
  },
  async:'true',
  success:function (data) {
    console.log('yes');
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Comment: What kind of error do you have? Please post your log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you're trying to get `JSONP` data from a URL, try this instead.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=sheikh+hasina',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
  }
});
```